# How to compute the integral $\int_{0}^{1} dx \int_{0}^{\sqrt{x}} e^{-y^2} dy$?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to compute the integral $\int_{0}^{1} dx \int_{0}^{\sqrt{x}} e^{-y^2} dy$.

My solution:
\begin{align}
& \int_{0}^{1} dx \int_{0}^{\sqrt{x}} e^{-y^2} dy \\
& = \int_{0}^{1} dy \int_{y^2}^{1} e^{-y^2} dx \\
& = \int_{0}^{1}  (1 - y^2) e^{-y^2} dy \\
& = \int_{0}^{1} e^{-y^2} dy - \int_{0}^1 y^2 e^{-y^2} dy \\
& = \int_{0}^{1} e^{-y^2} dy + \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^1 y d(e^{-y^2}) \\
& = \int_{0}^{1} e^{-y^2} dy + \frac{1}{2} y e^{-y^2}|_{0}^1 - \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^1 e^{-y^2} dy \\
& = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1} e^{-y^2} dy + \frac{1}{2} e^{-1/2}.
\end{align}

Is it possible to write compute explicitly $\int_{0}^{1} dx \int_{0}^{\sqrt{x}} e^{-y^2} dy$? Thank you very much.

Comment: You probably mean $\int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{x}} e^{-y^2} dy dx$, in the beginning right?

Comment: @An.Ditlev, yes.